# How can I get the route of a named outlet at the end of a navigation event in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to be able to get the full route of a named-outlet in Angular after a navigationEnd event. Is there a method that let's me choose the named-outlet? Is it also possible to have the data delivered as an Array value?

e.g.
**Example of Route**
`/home/somewhere(app-popup:my/named/outlet/route)`

```
this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        // get ActivatedRoute.outlet = "app-popup" ?
        console.log(event) // How can I get ['my', 'named', 'outlet', 'route'] ?
});
```